# How do i add up decimal values from a database

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add up the hours a user works for the last 7 days.  The hours are stored in the database as a decimal(18,2)

I have the correct SQL code for this as i can tally it up in sql server but when i try to output it onto a message box on the winform i get the following error

Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.'

i have tried

```
private void Hours_Week_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("****Conn String****");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM (Total_Hours_Day) FROM Sign_In_Out_Table , User_Table WHERE User_Table.FirstName = '" + Username_Alerts_lbl.Text + "'  AND Date between GETDATE()-7 and GETDATE()", conn);
    decimal TotalHoursWeek = Convert.ToDecimal(comm.ExecuteScalar());
    conn.Close();

    decimal sum = 0;
    sum += Convert.ToDecimal(TotalHoursWeek);

    MessageBox.Show(Username_Alerts_lbl.Text + " Hours worked = " + TotalHoursWeek);
}
```

I Expect to get the result where the values for the last 7 days on the database all tally up and show in a messageBox

Comment: Execute your query directly against the database and see what value you get. Also, read the error carefully: *Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types* and try to understand what the error is trying to tell you. If you don't understand the error, search that error online.

Comment: What is the type of Total_Hours_Day in Database?

Comment: the time field on a record may be null.Please check your records

Comment: Add an NVL to the sum, NVL(SUM (Total_Hours_Day),0)...while you are at it...fix your SQL injection risk as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error is self descriptive and clearly saying that `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to Other types`.

The command `Convert.ToDecimal(comm.ExecuteScalar())` has two part first one uses to fetch the data from db is `comm.ExecuteScalar()` which return an object and then `Convert.ToDecimal()` is trying to convert that object into decimal.

Issue is the `ExecuteScalar()` is not returning a decimal object it is returning an object with DBNull value.

A possible reason to return DbNull from DB instead of decimal is in your query you have two filter and first filter is  `User_Table. FirstName = Username_Alerts_lbl. Text` and it is possible that FirstName is not matched in DB that's why DB return null.